# Using a bootstrap treeview and have dynamic data - ASP.Net, c# - updated

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

Is there a way to have jquery call server side code (maybe an ajax handler?) I realize that I'm trying to mix client side and server side. I'm trying to populate a bootstrap treeview with dynamic data that have really convoluted rules. My rules include that depending on what is checked a sibling or even another path can be disabled when a node is checked.

So if the tree looks like:

```
A
  B
  C
D
  E
  F
  G
  H
```

When somebody clicks on E, F and H would be disabled but G not based on rules. When A is clicked D is disabled.

Unfortunately there is no rule like 'Everything on this level is disabled when a node is checked.' It's all data table driven and there's no 'logical' rules to apply to it.

I also need it to check all parents when a node is checked and when a node is deselected deselect all of the children.

And I need to be able to have people check/uncheck values.

TIA - Jeff.